# Disabling Custom module Overriding Adminhtml Block

Tags: module, blocks, overrides, magento-1

I'm Overriding Block. In module `Config.xml`

```
<config>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <modification>
            <class>Local_Modification_Block</class>
        </modification>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_group_edit_form>Local_Modification_Block_Customer_Group_Edit_Form</customer_group_edit_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

In `Local/Modification/Block/Customer/Group/Edit/Form.php` file content:

```
class Local_Modification_Block_Customer_Group_Edit_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Group_Edit_Form
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

All is working, **but**, if I disable this module from System -> Configuration -> Advanced "Local_Modification".
I'm not get any form...

Have ideas, what is wrong?

Comment: This is magento default behavior at magento.it is disable all activity of  this extension except observer/event.

Comment: Well, I think if the module is disabled, then should not do rewrite, and run the default Block...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding. "Disable modules output" does **not** disable the module, it only hides its own blocks, so it's a quick way to remove elements of a module from the frontend but does not disable any custom functionality.

To disable a module, you must edit the files in `app/etc/modules`:

```
<Local_Modification>
    <active>false</active>
</Local_Modification>
```